# Run block once before all capybara tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm using Capybara with Rspec for integration testing a rails app. Is there any way to run a before block once before the first Capybara test runs without it running before every feature spec? Putting a block in my RSpec.configure block as such causes it to run before each feature spec:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.before(:all, type: :feature) do
      # do some stuff
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are overengineering the task. Since you are to run it *once*, just run it:

```
cb = lambda { puts 'I am run once' }
RSpec.configure do |config|
  cb.call
end
```

Comment: I didn't think to do this because I needed the capybara dsl to run the commands I needed, but then I realized I could still access them from within the spec_helper by simply prepending them with 'Capybara'. Thank you!

Comment: ...or by including respective `Capybara::DSL` or whatever it’s called, I have no access to the source at the moment. Welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.before(:suite) do
      # do some stuff
    end
end
```